# Realizar uma pesquisa a partir de uma determinada data

Tags: java, data

Estou lendo um arquivo csv que gera dados de quando uma determinada pagina foi acessada. Porém não estou conseguindo implementar um metodo que possibilite que eu possa realizar a pesquisa a partir de uma data que eu desejar. 
Segue o codigo

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class httpcompleto {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader httpcompleto = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("http-completo.csv"));
        String line = "";
        String date;
        while((line = httpcompleto.readLine()) != null ){
            String[] row = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(row[0] + " - " + row[1] + " - " + row[2] + " - " + row[3] + " - " + row[4]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o formato da linha? Comente uma delas aqui para eu ver.

Comment: {M7H1-V0BD21MJ-5619JXLH} - 02/02/2010 09:43:44 - DTAA/BJM0311 - PC-2790 - "http://yahoo.com"

Answer (score 0):

1. Para facilitar o processamento, crie uma classe `Linha` para representar a linha.
2. A cada linha lida do arquivo, instancie um objeto `Linha` com os dados lidos.
3. Armazene o objeto instanciado em uma lista.
4. Percorra a lista, procurando os itens que tenham a data desejada.

**Observações:**

Para facilitar a comparação da data, transforme-a em `Calendar`. Você pode fazer assim:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("02/02/2010 09:43:44"));
```

Um exemplo de classe `Linha`:

```
class Linha {

    public static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    private String campo0;
    private Calendar campo1;
    private String campo2;
    private String campo3;
    private String campo4;

    public Linha(String campo0, String campo1, String campo2, String campo3, String campo4) throws Exception {
        this.campo0 = campo0;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(campo1));
        this.campo1 = cal;

        this.campo2 = campo2;
        this.campo3 = campo3;
        this.campo4 = campo4;
    }

    public String getCampo0 () { return campo0; };
    public Calendar getCampo1 () { return campo1; };
    public String getCampo2 () { return campo2; };
    public String getCampo3 () { return campo3; };
    public String getCampo4 () { return campo4; };

}
```